# How to filter tags by category in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, categories, posts

I am trying to filter the tags depending on which category you are on. For example if I clicked on 'Bespoke Legacy Support' which has three posts:

Post One - Tag: Artificial Intelligence
Post Two - Tag: CRM
Post Three - Tag: Artificial Intelligence

Then the sidebar filters will only show 'Artificial Intelligence and CRM', but at the moment it shows all tags that aren't empty under 'Filter by Product', please see a screenshot below of how this looks:

[image: sidebar filters]

The code I have got at the moment is:

```
$tags = get_tags(array(
    'cat' => '62',
    'hide_empty' => true
));
    
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $class = ( $tag_id == $tag->term_id ) ? 'active' : '';

    echo '<p><a class="' .$class. '" href="/category/case-studies/bespoke-legacy-support?tags=' . $tag->term_id . '&tagname=' .$tag->name. '&catname=' .$cat_id. '">' . $tag->name . '';
    if($catfiltern == '62') {
        echo ' (' .$tag->count. ')</a></p>';
    } else {
        echo '</a></p>';
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help with this and anything else you need to know I can share.

I've tried changing the 'cat' ID but when I change this ID the page breaks and doesn't show anything.